# Getting error in maxium number as - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python

New to python, in this code when compiling gives me the error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)/2)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)/2)   File "main.py", line 5, in maximum
lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)/2)   [Previous line repeated 52 more times]   File "main.py", line 3, in maximum
return A[r] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Here is the Code:

```
def maximum(A,l,r):
  if(r-l == 0):
    return A[r]

  lmax = maximum(A,l,(l+r)/2)
  rmax = maximum(A,(l+r/2)+1,r)
  print(lmax,rmax)
  if(rmax<lmax):
    return lmax
  else:
    return rmax

A = [9,12,15,5,2]
maximum(A,1,5)
```

This is the algorithm i took to convert to code:
[image]

Comment: You see the problem, right?  `(l+r)/2` is a floating point operation.  If you want an integer division, use `(l+r)//2`.

Comment: @TimRoberts, this solved the problem for Type error. but then this gives me the recursion error.

Comment: Recursion always need to have some condition to be stopped. You can take a look at this example (fibonacci with recursion) to get a good grasp on that. https://pastebin.com/mSDkE10T

Comment: @YalchinMammadli, can you suggest me any condition ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious that **the index of a list can not be float**.

`(l+r)/2` and `r/2`  use true division `/`, and in true division the result of dividing two integers is a float.

so replace `/` with floor division `//`.

see this [ref](https://prosperocoder.com/posts/python/true-division-vs-floor-division/).

And to avoid recursion, we need a condition to return from the `maximum` function.

Comment: can you suggest me any condition that can be applied here

Answer (score 0):

At one point you make r=1.0 (float because of the division) by calling maximum function inside maximum function. When you call maximum funtion with r = 1.0 and l =1, difference is now 0.0 and r = 1.0 float and then you try to access list as A[1.0] which throws an error.